# First package for typesetting commutative diagrams

Tags: diagrams, tex-history

What was the first package for typesetting commutative diagrams in Latex and when was it made available?

Comment: you can typeset commutative diagrams in the picture environment, which has been available as long as latex, but isn't a "package"

Comment: Possibly `amscd`, based on the features available in AMS-TeX, but it just produced rectangular diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a comparison between packages for commutative diagrams in a [very nice paper by Gabriel Vicente Feruglio on TUGboat](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb15-4/tb45vali.pdf), issued in 1994.

According to the bibliography, the first available package (besides using directly `picture` mode) was the one by John Reynolds, `diagmac.sty` issued in 1987 and still available as `diagmac2` (some patches were introduced by Bob Tennent in order to make the package use `pict2e` facilities).

The porting of AMS-TeX to LaTeX pushed several people to do the switch and this prompted the development of the other packages described in Feruglio's paper.